# Robotium testcase

Tags: android, robotium

I have a Robotium test case and It should be like

- UI Application starts uploading data to server
- User swaps to some other application on the device
- uploading operation is running at the background
- user comes to the main UI application

How to keep track of uploading the data at background? can we use multithreading  for this?

```
 try {
        mSolo.clickOnMenuItem("UPLOAD");
        mSolo.sleep(1000);
        Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
        inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
        mSolo.waitForActivity(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);
        mSolo.goBack();
        mSolo.assertCurrentActivity("main",
                UIActivity.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is this code correct? If not suggest me a modification or correct code.

Help is always appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: This code is running but I m not sure about it.

Comment: I want to implement UI and background thread as well,How can I do this so that eventhough the user comes back, the background thread shouldnt get killed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interact with other applications unless you signed the third party application with your own key (see [black box testing](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC0QFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Frobotium.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FRobotiumForBeginners.pdf&ei=f5QMVd5fg-Rq6YuAWA&usg=AFQjCNGxQ9yW3AXVraiazdgNEz8qAz_TTw&sig2=QDDhcbD-6TrBvH-pI3N0mw&bvm=bv.89060397,d.d2s&cad=rja)).

But what you can is pressing *Home*, *Back* and starting Intents. The following code is untested but hopefully gives you an idea:

```
try {
    mSolo.clickOnMenuItem("UPLOAD"); // start upload
    mSolo.sleep(1000);
    mSolo.goBack(); // leave app
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.company.another.app.SomeActivity");
    startActivity(inent); // start another app
    ...
    // option one: get app context and use it for access on preferences, etc.
    Context context = this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();  
    // option two: wait for logs that you write while uploading     
    solo.waitForLogMessage("Upload completed");
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.myapp.MyMainUIActivity");
    startActivity(inent); // start own Main Activity again
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So  you could use log messages, preferences or any other methods of your app in order to follow up the upload progress.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leave your application and run it again with Instrumentation. This part is not correct:

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

Why do you create new instrumentation? You can simply run:

```
getInstrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

by the way, solo.goBack() just does it, so it doesn't make sense to call it with instrumentation. I would simply rewrite it to:

```
try {
    mSolo.clickOnMenuItem("UPLOAD");
    mSolo.sleep(1000);
    mSolo.goBack();
    assertTrue(mSolo.waitForActivity(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS));
    mSolo.goBack();
    mSolo.assertCurrentActivity("main", UIActivity.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but Its crashing here  assertTrue(mSolo.waitForActivity(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS));